# How do I add width to the bars in barchart. I am using recharts library with reactjs

Tags: reactjs, recharts

In this code I have one sample json where I have provided name, value and width for the barchart.

```
import React from "react";
import { Bar, BarChart, ResponsiveContainer, Tooltip } from "recharts";

interface BarData {
  name: string;
  value: number;
  width: number;
}

const data: BarData[] = [
  {
    name: "Bar 1",
    value: 10,
    width: 100,
  },
  {
    name: "Bar 2",
    value: 20,
    width: 200,
  },
  {
    name: "Bar 3",
    value: 30,
    width: 300,
  },
];

const Barchart: React.FC = () => {
  return (
    <ResponsiveContainer height={400}>
      <BarChart data={data} layout="horizontal" barGap={10}>
        <Bar
          dataKey="value"
          width={(bar) => bar.width}
          fill="#5e5e5e"
          radius={[0, 0, 0, 0]}
        />
        <Tooltip />
      </BarChart>
    </ResponsiveContainer>
  );
};

export default Barchart;
```

ChatGPT provided me this code. But this doesn't work. If there is another way to add width to the bar then mention them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to use a custom shape for your Bar component.

In your data, you add a new property, `customWidth` (it cannot be named as `width` as it will be overwritten by recharts.

```
const data: BarData[] = [
  {
    name: "Bar 1",
    value: 10,
    customWidth: 100,
  },
  {
    name: "Bar 2",
    value: 20,
    customWidth: 200,
  },
  {
    name: "Bar 3",
    value: 30,
    customWidth: 300,
  },
];
```

In your `<Bar />` component, use the `shape` property to define a custom shape.

For example

```
<Bar
  dataKey="amount"
  isAnimationActive={false}
  onClick={(value) => console.log(value)}
  shape={(props) => (
    <CustomBar
      {...props}
      width={props.width}
      displayACH={displayACH}
      displayFailed={displayFailed}
      displayDisputed={displayDisputed}
    />
  )}
/>
```

Then you create another custom bar component where you assign a new width

```
function CustomBar(props) {
  console.log(props);
  return <Rectangle {...props} width={props.customWidth} />;
}
```

Here's an [example stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-2bqdym?file=src%2FApp.js).